# How to delete blank cells and shift data to the left on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, transpose

I am trying to remove the empty cells on my sheet and move only the non-empty cells to the left. I get the data from Google Form where it has many sections and some sections are skipped depending on their answers.

Some sections are left blank, therefore I need to get rid of the empty cells and shift only the non-empty cells to the left. I have tried Trim and Transpose but I can't execute them well (data of the cells are fit into one cell).

This is how my sheet looks:
[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT1Zv.png)

I want it to look like this:
[target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDTGg.png)

here is the link of the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DmyrqtSl4a9t2cbPZ2kqeQAseiEOth0g21tU3mn14Qs/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet. That will make it a lot easier to find a solution.

Comment: @JPV i have edited my post just now, thank you about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a second sheet (tab) and in A2 try

```
=ArrayFormula({Sheet1!A2:A, trim(split(transpose(query(transpose(if(len(Sheet1!B2:K), Sheet1!B2:K&"~",)),,9^9)), "~"))})
```

and see if that works?

[image]

Note: depending on your locale you may have to change the above formula to

```
=ArrayFormula({Sheet1!A2:A\ trim(split(transpose(query(transpose(if(len(Sheet1!B2:K); Sheet1!B2:K&"~";));;9^9)); "~"))})
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much. @JPV can you help me figure out what functions on the formula do to the data? the previous code that i've used is kinda the same but I'm still confused.

Comment: I really appreciate it @JPV, i've been researching and trying to figure out functions and making codes for over two days now. I want to understand it so i can do more. I'm not really proficient in coding but i can understand how stuff works.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of @JPVs answer:

The trick is to use QUERY(data, query, [headers]) with no query and a very big number for headers (9^9). It concatenates all cells in every column into one cell, separating them with spaces.
[query with only header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HH1K.png)

To do the same with rows, transpose the data before and after:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(your_range), , number_of_columns))
```

[query wrapped in transpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YD02.png)

To split cells back, add ~ to every non empty cell before joining them with QUERY, and split by ~ afterwards.

ARRAYFORMULA applies single cell operations on whole range.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(your_range&"~")` will add ~ to every cell in range. Using LEN and IF we add it only to non empty cells. LEN returns length of a string. If length of cell value is not 0, add ~, else leave blank: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(your_range), your_range&"~", ))` We could do IF(LEN(...) > 0, ... but numeric values are already treated as TRUE if different than 0 an FALSE if 0.

[added ~ to non empy cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymv6D.png)

Now combine both into

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(your_range), your_range&"~", )), , number_of_columns)))
```

[before split and trim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n99yD.png)

All values whith spaces and ~s are now in one column. We need to split them by ~ back to more cells, and remove spaces, added by QUERY. SPLIT(text, "~") and TRIM(text) will do this.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(your_range), your_range&"~", )), , number_of_columns)), "~")))
```

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dykjI.png)

This doesnt work with dates, that is why `{Sheet1!A2:A, ... }` was added to treat first column separately and only apply solution to other columns.

Note that spaces at the beginnings and ends of cells will be removed, and cells, that contain ~ will be separated. A workaround is to use another character, that is not present in your data instead of ~.